# How to take some information about a website to an android app?

Tags: android

what i mean is for example when someone has a Blog and they make an app for it, but they don't update the app everytime they publish a new note or whatever you want to call it. So, how do you make to show some information about a website?
Not the website indeed, if not, taking the data and converting it to a string of an Android app.

For example with this:

[LOLKING application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lolsummoners)

In this application they took information of a user searched and it's shown in the application.

Or even when you go to History (of matchs) in League of Legends, you will see the information that comes from his website. They even get the images and more..
By the way, i'm aware that you can get the entire website showed with a webview, please understand i don't want that, i want to convert data from a website to ImageView, TextView, Button on Android.

How it's called and how to be done? with a simple example i think might work (and it's easier to understand so **please write** me a simple **code example**).

Comment: you have to retrieve data from website to your app, so search for retrieve data with json, it's popular way for that.

Comment: @IbrahimAli do you know any good website that provides a guide starting from zero on Json?